# Device not getting disconnected

Tags: ios, google-cast, chromecast

I have integrated the functionality of chrome casting in my iPhone app. The problem I am facing is that when the casting is not started and sometimes even when casting is in progress, I press the disconnect device button but nothing happens. My code for disconnecting is :

```
-(void)disconnectDevice{
[self.deviceManager stopApplication];
[self.deviceManager removeChannel:self.mediaControlChannel];
[self.deviceManager disconnect];
self.mediaControlChannel = nil;
self.deviceManager = nil;
self.selectedDevice = nil;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is your receiver handling the disconnected state? The template code looks something like:

```
window.castReceiverManager = cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.getInstance();

castReceiverManager.onSenderDisconnected = function(event) {
    console.log('Received Sender Disconnected event: ' + event.data);
    if (window.castReceiverManager.getSenders().length == 0) {
           window.close();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use one line to stop the media

```
[self.mediaControlChannel stop]
```

if you still have the problem enable the logging on the **sender application**, you can also see the logging on the **receiver side** to see what happening